# Why PHP include is not working?

Tags: php, function, session, include

I'm trying to make a page view counter. I'm a newbie to PHP. Here is my problem:
I'm using this code in "index.php":

```
<?php
    include "visitcounter.php";
?>
```

And using the following code in "visitcounter.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['visitcount']) {
    $_SESSION['visitcount'] = $_SESSION['visitcount']+1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['visitcount'] = 1;
}

echo "Total Page Views = ".$_SESSION['visitcount'];

?>
```

The problem is the page index.php is showing server error. If I change the code with the following code in index.php:

```
<?php
    include "/visitcounter.php";
?>
```

Then the page not show any error message but display nothing. Anyone please help me to figure out what is the wrong I'm doing.

Comment: after `session_start()`, a semicolon is missing

Comment: which the complete address of this page? Where is she? What is the folder hierarchy of the page?

Comment: look at error logs if something isnt working correctly

Comment: add the semicolon. still got the same problem.

Comment: Your missing a bracket on the first if `if(isset($_SESSION['visitcount']) {`, dude turn on error reporting before you come here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the point mentioned of Silvio Silva is the problem.

Change from:

```
session_start()
```

to:

```
session_start();
```

To avoid such problems in future, just add to the file:

```
ini_set("display_errors","on");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will show you such errors then directly in the output, so that you can find it easier.